# Erro "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" ao efetuar consulta no banco de dados para retornar de quantidade de registros

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Tenho uma **query** em **ADO .NET** com o objetivo de **retornar a quantidade de registros** que tenho no banco com base no mês e ano passados. Por exemplo, eu passo a data **"27/01/2021"** e recebo a **quantidade** de **registros** que tenho no banco referentes a **"01/2021"**.
O problema acontece se eu não tiver nenhum registro gravado no banco, ai recebo o erro:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter
> 'index') System.Collections.Generic.List.get_Item(int index)

Se já tenho pelo menos um registro no banco não recebo esse erro, tentei algumas coisas, porém não consegui nenhuma solução para esse erro. Segue a minha query:

```
public int RetornaQuantidadeCuponsMes(string numDocumento, string idProduto, string dataImportacao)
        {
            var conexao = AbrirConexao();
            var comando = conexao.CreateCommand();
            comando.CommandText =
                "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@dataEfetivacao,'%Y-%m') AS data, " +
                "(SELECT COUNT(cupom) FROM campanhaCupons AS c2 " +
                "WHERE DATE_FORMAT(c2.dataEfetivacao,'%Y-%m') = data AND numDocumento = @numDocumento  AND idProduto = @idProduto) " +
                "AS qtdCupons " +
                "FROM campanhaCupons AS c1";
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("numDocumento", numDocumento);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("idProduto", idProduto);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("dataEfetivacao",
                Convert.ToDateTime(dataImportacao).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
            var cooperado = ExecutaComandoComRetorno(comando);

            var cuponsNoMes = cooperado[0]["qtdCupons"];

            return Convert.ToInt32(cuponsNoMes);
        }
```

Comment: Da erro na linha do `var cuponsNoMes`?

Comment: *"O problema acontece se eu não tiver nenhum registro gravado no banco"*  baseado nessa afirmação, se fizer assim `var cuponsNoMes = cooperado[0]["qtdCupons"];` sem validar primeiro se `cooperado` retornou algum valor vai dar erro, primeiro precisa validar se tem dados em `cooperado`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como citado pelo @RicardoPontual no comentário da pergunta, o correto é **verificar se há itens na sua lista antes**, para evitar exceções do tipo [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0), quando tenta acessar um índice fora dos valores aceitados em uma lista, algo como:

```
if (cooperado != null && cooperado.Count > 0) {
```

A depender da implementação da estrutura de dados que está retornando, pode ser que a propriedade que te disponibiliza o tamanho da lista seja `Length`, `Count` ou `Count()` (o **método** `Count` é um método de extensão do namespace [System.Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0)).

Verificar se `cooperado` é diferente de `null` não é obrigatório, mas é recomendado para também evitar uma [NullReferenceException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception?view=net-5.0) (quando tenta acessar uma propriedade de um valor `null`).

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Exatamente o que precisava, debugando vi que quando vazio o Count estava vindo 0, então consegui tratar o erro. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O `cooperado` está vindo vazio pois não tem nenhum registro. Uma forma simples de resolver isso é com um `if`:

```
var cooperado = ExecutaComandoComRetorno(comando);
if (cooperado is null) // Se não tiver dados, retorna 0
    return 0;

var cuponsNoMes = cooperado[0]["qtdCupons"];
return Convert.ToInt32(cuponsNoMes);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, na verdade o cooperado já vem com o Count 0, mais ai foi so verificar se ele estava recebendo 0 e tratar antes de adicionar no array, muito obrigado pela ajuda.